# VueJS 2: Bind v-for index to id attribute on mouseover

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseover, vuejs2

I'm using a `v-for` directive on a `li` element to produce a set of images from an array. On mousing over the image, I would like to change the `id` attribute of the specific image I moused over to be `'drag'`, and I would like this image to be the only element to have the `id` of `'drag'`.

I've tried binding to `:id` using an inline statement like you would for `:class`, but it doesn't work and simply replaces the id with `[object Object]`.

Here I've bound to `:class` and it behaves correctly:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [{
      Name:'Object 1', link:'obj1.jpg'
    }, {
      Name:'Object 2', link:'obj2.jpg'
    }, {
      Name:'Object 3', link:'obj3.jpg'
    }],
    dragIndex: "",
  },
  methods: {
    drag(item,index) {
      console.log("Dragging " + item)
    },
    startDragID(index) {
      this.dragIndex = index
      console.log("Element Prepped For Drag: " + index)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li 
      v-for="(items,index) in list" 
      draggable="true" 
      @mouseenter="startDragID(index)" 
      @dragstart="drag(items.link,index)"
      :class="{'drag' : dragIndex == index , 'not-drag' : dragIndex != index}"
    >{{items.Name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Added code to show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue does not support binding to the `id` property using the inline [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) like it does the `class` and `style` properties.

You can create a method to calculate the appropriate id value based on a given `index`:

```
methods: {
  getID(index) {
    return (index == this.dragIndex) ? 'drag' : false;
  }
}
```

And bind that result to the `id` attribute:

```
<li v-for="(items, index) in list" :id="getID(index)">
```

---

Or, since the method for determining the id is simple enough, you could add the logic inline:

```
<li v-for="(items, index) in list" :id="(index == dragIndex) ? 'drag' : false">
```